# Importing local file dir into SVN repo with TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, windows-vista, tortoisesvn

This is my first time trying to use any SCM so please bear with me.

Following the SVN manual, I create a repo in an empty directory. All good.

Then I try to import an existing project folder. I'm using the shell command but it's like this:

```
Import C:\Users\aaa\SVN\proj to file:///C:/proj_2
Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
Unable to open repository 'file:///C:/proj_2'
Finished!
```

I'm  probably doing something very incorrectly. Thanks.

Comment: What are the actual commands you're typing to do that? Also, what are the actual commands you used to create the repository?

Comment: could you indicate how you created your local repository? The url `file:///C:/proj_2` looks funny (not something like `file:///C:/svnrepo` or similar?

Comment: @Greg, no commands. I'm using the Shell from Tortoise.

Comment: @Vladimir, actually C:\Users\aaa\SVN\proj is my repository that I'm trying to add files to, to populate for the first time. file:///C:/proj_2 is the currently directory that some of my files are in. Thanks.

Comment: @Vladimir, @scribble, I checked this similar question http://stackoverflow.com/q/1412256/351903 and this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412256/import-on-tortoisesvn/1412272#1412272. I found that, trying to import something to the newly created repository gives the same error that you got. However doing a checkout of the empty repository, overwriting the folder structure of the checkout location with the necessary files/folders and then committing those to the repository works. I still don't know what is the actual problem with importing to empty repository and why it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quick and dirty trick but you can use TurtoiseSVN, browse the local repository, create a remote folder and check it out into the directory you wan to import.

After that, you only have to select the local folder, right-click and select "check-in" to commit your local files.

Additionally with TurtoiseSVN's repo-browser you will be able to see the real location of your repository.

Answer (score 0):

Does the directory c:\proj_2 exist and contain a svn repository?

If not, you'll need to initialize the repository first by:

1. create the folder c:\proj_2
2. right-click the folder -> TortoiseSVN -> Create Repository Here

The retry your import as above.

Alternately, if you want all your projects in a single repository:

1. create c:\svn-repos the same way as above
2. import to svn URL file:///c:/svn-repos/proj_2 -- the import operation will create the proj_2 sub-folder in the repository and add your file to it