# How do I put an existing Visual Studio solution under source control using VisualSVN Server?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server, visualsvn

I have an existing Visual Studio 2013 solution, and I want to put it under source control using VisualSVN Server. I installed VisualSVN Server and created a new blank repository. Their [Getting Started](https://www.visualsvn.com/server/getting-started/) page doesn't explain how to add a folder structure and files to the repository. I am expecting an import or add files option when right clicking on the repository node in the UI.

How do I add an exiting root folder and all its files and folders of a Visual Studio solution to a repository and make it ready so any SVN client can check out files from it? I am planning to use [TortoiseSVN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TortoiseSVN) as the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) and [check out a working copy](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-checkout.html) of the repository. Copy from solution into the working copy, select all files, and make a rightclick and select [TortoiseSVN -> Add](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-add.html).

[Commit the changes](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-commit.html) and now you have the data added to the repository.

Comment: I don't know what "check out a working copy of the Repository" means. What working copy? The repository is empty. Can you explain the steps.

Comment: To make changes to a repo you need a working copy, even if the repository is empty. I added the help link of checkout.

Comment: I followed the steps from this question but I will accept this answer because I think they are similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412256/import-on-tortoisesvn