# Migrating from webstorm to Visual Studio 2015 - importing files from subversion using ankhsvn

Tags: visual-studio, svn, ankhsvn

I have been using the Webstorm trial version for a month and it has expired, so now I am considering using Visual Studio.

However, I have come across a stumbling block using ankhsvn, which is that I cannot figure out how to "import" files from existing files in subversion and add them to a project. `Add to Subversion` simply adds a new folder to the repo and I cannot see the existing files in the project explorer.

Is there a **newbie friendly** tutorial on how to import files from an existing svn repo to a solution in local space?

Answer (score 0):

D'oh! Turns out I just needed to [use Tortoise to check out the files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27180062/how-to-put-an-existing-visual-studio-solution-under-source-control-using-visuals), then create a blank solution *in the same folder* as the check out (this is important or ankhsvn won't play nice), and then add existing website to the project.